# Lenovo T440 touchpad not recognised

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, synaptics

With the risk of repeating already asked question, I decided to ask one of my own, because I didn't see a post about (potential) conflicting touchpad drivers. Brief story:

1. installed (ed)Ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo t440, touchpad was recognised and worked sort of OK.
2. all of a sudden, it started being not recognised as a multitouch, just a s a touchpad/mouse.
3. I searched all kind of solutions to make it a multitouch one again, whose order I forgot already, but included x.org, editing ppas (.conf.d) etc.

My strong suspicion now is that I have messed up so many conflicting solutions that that's why the touchpad is not even recognised. (on "xinput" command it does not even appear)

How do I revert all changes and go back to factory settings of ubuntu, or solve the (potential) conflicts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/how-to-configure-debian-with-thinkpad-t440-trackpad-clickpad -----> Tried to post the code, but wasn't working. Conf file is there with instructions.

You can restore gnome-specific settings with the following commands in terminal:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

For details you can see How to Reset Ubuntu/Gnome Settings to Defaults without Re-installing | Linux FUD

Additionally you can verify that there are no broken dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

And then you can troubleshoot your remaining problems one-by-one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kali, for your quick response. Sadly, the above command did not work, and my touchpad (Multitouch clickpad) and pointer not working.

In fact, the cursor does not even show upon rebooting/login screen, and only moves after I plug in the mouse. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.